# Access nested lists in Observable Collection for Binding

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, xamarin, observablecollection

I have response objects that are added to an observable collection in my
controller like below

```
public void AddRoutes(IRestResponse response)
{
    ScheduleDownloadResponse json =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScheduleDownloadResponse(response.Content);

    ScreenController.Instance.route = new
    ObservableCollection<ScheduleRoute>();
    ScreenController.Instance.vehicle = new
    ObservableCollection<Vehicle>();

    ScreenController.Instance.pickups = new
    ObservableCollection<Pickup>();
    ScreenController.Instance.compartment = new
    ObservableCollection<Compartment>();

    foreach (var item in json.Routes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(json.Routes);
        ScreenController.Instance.route.Add(item);

        foreach(var vehicle in item.Vehicles)
        {
            ScreenController.Instance.vehicle.Add(vehicle);

            foreach (var compartment in vehicle.Compartments)
            {

                ScreenController.Instance.compartment.Add(compartment);
            }
        }
```

Inside the ScheduleRoute is other response objects eg. Vehicles contains
the Compartment object. Pickup contains the Supplier Object. All response
objects are within there own observable collection

```
"Routes": [
 {
 "Id": 1,
 "Date": "2015-03-04T00:00:00",
 "Area": "2887",
 "Detail": "",
 "Driver": "",
 "SampleType": "",
 "Schedule": "A",
 "Tag": "",
 "Vehicles": [
  {
    "VehicleId": 22,
     "VehicleRego": "RRK160",
     "Primary": true,
     "Compartments": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Capacity": 8000.0,
        "Product": ""
      }
]
},
"Pickups": [
{
     "Quantity": 6300.0,
     "Id": 1,
    "Vat": 0,
    "Hazards": "",
    "Latitude": "-34.33000000000",
    "Longitude": "-63.29119000000",
    "Message": "",
    "Supplier": {
    "Id": 1134,
    "Name": "GUTIERREZ REMO O. Y RODOLFO S."
 },
"Product": "Milk",
"ProductKey": "2",
 "Ticket": "",
 "EstmatedPickup": "2015-03-04T20:00:00+13:00"
 },
```

In the view I need to display the route id,date,schedule, area and the
VehicleRego from Vehicles and the Id from supplier.

In my View model I have a Schedule that is a copy of the original
collection from my Screen controller

```
Schedule = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleRoute>();
Schedule = ScreenController.Instance.route;
```

I'm writing a mobile pcl application in Xamarin and in the Xaml I am binding to Schedule  and can display all first level
attributes in scheduleRoute but dont know how to get to Vehicles.VehicleRego and
Vehicles.Suppliers.Id

Being new to C# Im not sure how to either access the nested levels from scheduleRoute or
combine 3 collection objects(ScheduleRoute, Vehicle and Supplier) to
retrieve values

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `Collections` of `Vehicles`, you need to select one of them. You can provide a `Where()` clause, get the `First()` or `Last()` result, or just select. Let's say you have a `route`, a `pickup`, and the `vehicle Id`:

```
public void GetInfo(Route route, Pickup pickup, int vehicleId)
{
    Console.WriteLine(route.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(route.Date);
    Console.WriteLine(route.Schedule);

    var vehicle = route.Vehicles.Where(v => v.vehicleId == vehicleId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (vehicle != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(vehicle.VehicleRego);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(pickup.Supplier.Id);
}
```

Unless you have **circular references** between `route`, `pickup` `supplier` and `vehicle`, there is no way to just "guess" the information. You have to provide them just like I did.